# aws get-caller-identity behaving differently via ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, boto3, aws-sts

I have an ansible playbook which runs following task from a jenkins job

```
- name: printing get caller
  shell: "aws sts get-caller-identity"
  register: var_caller

- debug:
    msg: "{{var_caller.stdout}}"
```

And returns the following output

```
ok: [local-server] => {
    "msg": {
        "Account": "8693XXXXXX",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::8693XXXXXX:user/user-A",
        "UserId": "AIDAJEXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
}
```

And when i run the same command manually from command line, it gives assumed-role output and account-id is also different

```
[root@local-server] aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "AROAZXXXXXXXX:i-01143d8XXXXXXX",
    "Account": "653XXXXXXX",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::653XXXXXXX:assumed-role/role-A/i-01143d8XXXXXXX"
}
```

Isn't it supposed to return the same thing? What could be the misconfiguration here?

NOTE : I'm not using any kind of aws credentials, the ec2 `local-server` has IAM Role assigned `role-A`.

Answer (score 1):

On `ansible [core 2.13.3]` the output is the same:

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "{",
        "    \"UserId\": \"AIDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\",",
        "    \"Account\": \"1234567891011\",",
        "    \"Arn\": \"arn:aws:iam::1234567891011:user/username\"",
        "}"
    ]
}
```

```yaml
aws sts get-caller-identity                                                                                                         
{
    "UserId": "AIDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Account": "1234567891011",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567891011:user/username"
}
```

Please avoid using shell commands in Ansible.
Always use modules when possible.
For your case there is the [aws_caller_info_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_caller_info_module.html)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: Get the current caller identity information
    amazon.aws.aws_caller_info:
    register: var_caller

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ var_caller }}"
```

```yaml
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "account": "1234567891011",
        "account_alias": "account-alias",
        "arn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567891011:user/username",
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "user_id": "AIDXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
}
```

You can then get the single values like this:

```yaml
- debug:
      msg: "{{ var_caller.user_id }}"
```